# Firebase React Native build error after linking module

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, react-native

I'm attempting to use the firestack module to implement social media signin into my React Native project: https://github.com/fullstackreact/react-native-firestack

However after linking the module, I am receiving the following error during the build:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
java.io.IOException: Could not delete path 'C:\Users\######\project\android\app\build\generated\source\r\debug\android'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete build directory in android/app and try `react-native run-android`